# How to make edges smoooth/rounded?

Tags: node-editor, vertices, edges, subdivision-surface, bevel

[image]

This is a small part of the object I want to smoothen so fixing the vertices will take time,
is there a fast way to smoothen the lip of edges of my cylinder?

Exactly like this.
[image]

Things I tried but didn't worked:
Subdivision surface modifier,
Bevel modifier,
Bevel node- doesn't look good,
Edit mode Bevel

I provided the blender file below so you'll see the object I'm talking about.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Select your object, right click, smooth shade.

Comment: Thank you but I'm trying to figure out how to geometrically change the lip of the cylinder rounded.

Comment: Unfortunately, a quick, easy (or even a rather time consuming) method for rounding the topology of your edge is not possible due to the mesh being triangulated to the extent that it is. I even tried a few common, quick methods to convert the mesh back to quads, but to no avail. Is there any reason you can't use a quad based mesh instead?

Comment: Actually, unless he wants to keep the current topology, he can quicky correct it with X > Limited Dissolve for example

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I am trying to make svg(vector format) turn into 3d but I'm finding hard it to soften them. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=AQY90K0L" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/AQY90K0L/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your topology is not good so the bevel won't work properly, what you can do is:

- First apply the scale, otherwise the bevel will be deformed on an axis:

[image]

- Go in *Edit* mode, you have a lot of triangles, a quick way to fix it is to select all and <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* (the default settings will work fine):

[image]

Delete the top faces with <kbd>X</kbd> > *Faces*:

[image]

- You need to delete some rebel vertices along the edge with <kbd>X</kbd> > *Dissolve Vertices*:

[image]

- Enable the *LoopTools* addon, select the top edges and right click > *LoopTools > Bridge* to create new faces:

[image]

- Select the top edges and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to bevel. You can tweak all the settings in the *Operator* box (bottom left of your 3D view):

[image]

Comment: Hi! This one is what I'm looking for. It worked! Thank you!